# Static Library Dependency not being included in binary

Tags: ios

I have built a static library (let's call it A) that depends on CFNetwork.framework, which is being successfully built in xCode. I have included CFNetwork.framework in the "link binary with libraries" build phase. This static library has its own project.

For some reason, when try to use this static library in another project (let's call it B), it fails in the linking phase, complaining that CFNetwork's symbols could not be found.

I have added A as a dependency in B's target (so that A always gets compiled before B successfully) and I also have added A to B's "Link Binary With Libraries" build phase.

Has anyone ever had a similar issue?

EDIT: If I add CFNetwork.framework to B's "Link Binary With Libraries" build it starts building successfully.

Comment: I am having the exact same issue, but with the MediaPlayer.framework. Have you found a solution for this ?

Comment: Yeah... If you have a static library A that depends on MediaPlayer.framework, you should link MediaPlayer.framework against the executable (in the above example, B).

Static libraries don't get "copied" into one another

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will also need to add `CFNetwork.framework` as a dependency in project `B`.

That is the correct manner of setting up your dependencies.  You'll need to document the reliance upon `CFNetwork.framework` in the release notes for static library `A`.

Definitely have a look at [Guidelines for Creating Frameworks](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/macosx/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/CreationGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002254-BAJHGGGA), specifically "What to Include in Your Framework". You'll see that Apple advises against creating umbrella frameworks (i.e. including something like CFNetwork.framework in your distributed static library).

> **Don’t Create Umbrella Frameworks**
>
> While it is possible to create umbrella frameworks using Xcode, doing
>   so is unnecessary for most developers and is not recommended. Apple
>   uses umbrella frameworks to mask some of the interdependencies between
>   libraries in the operating system. In nearly all cases, you should be
>   able to include your code in a single, standard framework bundle.
>   Alternatively, if your code was sufficiently modular, you could create
>   multiple frameworks, but in that case, the dependencies between
>   modules would be minimal or nonexistent and should not warrant the
>   creation of an umbrella for them.

If you have a lot of dependencies, it's worth considering a dependency management tool like [Cocoapods](http://cocoapods.org).